# Making a complex animation be controlled by a simple value from 0 to 1

Tags: animation, keyframes, baking

Basically, I wanna convert a set of keyframes (If possible) into a simple custom slider, for example, I want to turn a set of 80+ keyframes across bone transforms and shape keys into a single 0 to 1 slider. I don't know if that's even possible, but would be nice if it is.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some time and tampering, I actually found out how to get this to work using drivers, No bones, none of that.

First I gave the object a custom property that was a float value that has a min of 0 and a max of 1, the name can be anything. I then would right-click the value and select **Copy as New Driver**. I would take that driver and apply it to any of my shape keys for my mesh, which could be a single key or multiple. Where this is different is I would instead right-click the driver and select **Open Drivers Editor** and change a few things, I would change the Type of driver from the default Averaged Value to Scripted Expression and within that expression, I would expand the value to something large or a pre define frame amount as I know some animations come from Unity or such. For now, I will set the value to NAME*600 for example, and the reason why we should do this is that the keys inside of the graph editor slide left and right at an increment of 1, so we need that space to add more keys in between. I would then add a start key and an end key from points 0 to 600 and just add a key between them for the animation I desire, after a bit of tweaking and editing, I have my own animation within a 0-1 slider where I could easily animate that 1 slider over everything to be able to reuse and easily manipulate a complex mesh.

Example:
[image: Example of the driver editor turning a animation into a single slider]

Answer (score 0):

For bone transforms you can store 1 frame of animation data as a pose in a Pose Library https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/armatures/posing/editing/pose_library.html

For a complex animation, what you can do is save a pose asset for each stage of the animation, then when you want to play it you can simply move between each pose you saved.

This doesn't solve the problem of shape keys since they don't get stored in a pose asset, but that can be setup. What you can do is setup a separate bone that will be a Driver for the shape key https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/drivers/index.html

Right-click the value bar of the shape key and press "Add a driver". Set your amateur as the target object. Then there will appear a bone section, and you'll select the bone that you want to control the shape key's value with. Now you should be able to change the value of the shape key by moving/rotating/scaling the assigned bone in pose mode. Since the bone's transform will be saved in the Pose Library, your shape keys will now be saved too.

Comment: I get the entire concept of storing them all as drivers and such, but the issue is that most of these keyframes are all going onto mostly shape keys while bone transforms are also a thing for later on, main problem is that there are 20+ shape keys being controlled with almost all undulating back and forth between 1 and 0 to create a seamless transition and control which I don't think I could do that well with bones and drivers, that's my issue and wanted to pack my animation into 1 slider I could animate on top of it all.

Comment: I don't have a lot of experience with it but I think the NLA editor, short for NonLinear Animation can do what you're after. https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/nla/introduction.html You could pack your entire animation into a single Action, then place it on the NLA editor, then you can do animations on top of it.

Comment: This might take me a little to tamper with, I'll let you know if this is my resolution when I get something done.

Answer (score 0):

The tool you're looking for is the "Action constraint", which has to be set on all bones you want to control, and then you will use a single channel transform of a new bone to drive the entire action, in a 0.0 - 1.0 fashion.

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/constraints/relationship/action.html

Comment: I don't guess this applies to shape keys as well, does it? Only bones?

Comment: You should use bones to drive shape keys values, so that the animation is bone-related only (and this is a general good practice, so to edit everything into one single action), and then use action constraint to have the single-slider behaviour.